# Cannot get vars displayed in my 'template' using Handlebars.js correctly

Tags: javascript, templates, wordpress, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars script that I am trying to get to iterate through an object to my 'template' below. Even though I can see the 'badNodes' in the object (an object when i do a console.log(row) it doesn't ever pass to the template and all I see is a blank entry next to address in the view/template.

Can anyone suggest what I may have done wrong - P.S I am new to Handlebars.js

```
<script class="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="badNodesContainer">
        {{#row}}
        <div class="hash{{badNodes.hash}} help-tip">
            <p>
                <strong>Address: </strong>{{badNodes.address}}</br>
            </p>
        </div>
        {{/row}}
    </div>
</script>
```

// latter part of ajax request

```
    .done(function (data, result, jqXHR) {
        var checkinData = JSON.parse(data).data;
        var rows = [];

        //_.templateSettings.variable = "badNode";
        var source = $("script.template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        $.each(checkinData, function (index, row) {
                row.badNodesHTML = "";
                var AB_action_login = '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="width:70px;text-align:left;" target="_blank" href="http://asite.com/app/login.php?username=' + row.user + '&hash=' + row.signature + '"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> App</a>';
                if (row.postid == null) {
                    var AB_action_order = '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm hidden" disabled="disabled" style="width:70px;text-align:left;" target="_blank" href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-admin/post.php?post=' + row.postid + '&action=edit"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> Order</a>';
                } else {
                    var AB_action_order = '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="width:70px;text-align:left;" target="_blank" href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-admin/post.php?post=' + row.postid + '&action=edit"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> Order</a>';
                }
                row.AB_login = AB_action_login;
                row.AB_order = AB_action_order;
                row.AB_actions = AB_action_login + AB_action_order;

                if (row.badNodes.length) {
                    $.each(row.badNodes, function (idx, badNode) {
                        badNode.address.toString()
                        badNode.address = /:(.+)/.exec(badNode.address)[1];
                        row.badNodesHTML += template(badNode);
                        row.AB_actions;
                    });
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the object via `#row` inside your template even though the object you pass into the template looks like this:

```
{
    hash: 'some hash',
    address: 'some address'
}
```

So, in order to bind it try to access it by key instead like this:

```
<script class="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="badNodesContainer">
        <div class="hash{{hash}} help-tip">
            <p>
                <strong>Address: </strong>{{address}}</br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Also, assuming that `badNodes` is an array of bad nodes, you could use `each` in your declaration when you pass `row` to the template directly. Try this:

```
<script class="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="badNodesContainer">
        {{#each badNodes}}
        <div class="hash{{hash}} help-tip">
            <p>
                <strong>Address: </strong>{{address}}</br>
            </p>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

I suggest you prepare a javascript object that has the exact shape and form you would like and then pass it to the template. You are formatting the output in an `$.each` loop and pass each row individually which could get messy from an organizational perspective. Also, you are creating html inside your javascript for the button which you could put in the template as well. Then, all you have to do is pass one `row` object to the template that has all required information.

A refactored version could look like this:

```
<style media="screen">
    .btn-zabs {
        width:70px;
        text-align:left;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    .done(function (data, result, jqXHR) {
        var checkinData = JSON.parse(data).data;
        var rows = [];

        var source = $("script.template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var $container = $("#parent-of-badNodesContainer");

        $.each(checkinData, function (index, row) {
            if (row.badNodes.length) {
                $.each(row.badNodes, function (idx, badNode) {
                    badNode.address.toString()
                    badNode.address = /:(.+)/.exec(badNode.address)[1];
                });
            }
        });

        $container.html(template(checkinData));
    });
</script>

<script class="template" type="text/html">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-zabs" target="_blank" href="http://asite.com/app/login.php?username={{user}}&hash={{signature}}"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> App</a>
    <div class="badNodesContainer">
        {{#each badNodes}}
        <div class="hash{{hash}} help-tip">
            <p>
                <strong>Address: </strong>{{address}}</br>
            </p>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{#if postid}}
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-zabs hidden" disabled="disabled" target="_blank" href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-admin/post.php?post={{postid}}&action=edit"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> Order</a>
    {{else}}
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-zabs" target="_blank" href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-admin/post.php?post={{postid}}&action=edit"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> Order</a>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Note, I put the button templates in an arbitrary spot. I'm sure you would want to re-organize where they belong. This is for demonstration only.